# How to catch Rotating Screen event of BlackBerry Torch 9800 OS 6?

Tags: blackberry

Could someone tell me how to catch this event?
Because when I rotated the phone to landscape mode, the app could not display correctly.
Thanks,
Duy

Answer (score 1):

When this happens then BB UI framework definitelly calls `layout(int width, int height)` for your screen. This is because `MainScreen` is also a `Manager`, so it should layout all its child fields before BB UI framework starts painting.

So in `layout()` you could track current orientation state (with `net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getOrientation()`) and compare with the previous one. If it is changed, then the device has just been rotated.

Comment: But we could not override layout() functions in MainScreen. In BB dev site, they said that: Receive notification when the orientation of the touch screen changes Import the net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager class. Override net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager.sublayout(int, int). protected void sublayout(int width, int height) { .. 
I did but the simulator did not run to the code when I rotating the screen. I do not this is a simulator issue or what.
Thanks anyway,

Comment: Torch 9800 may behave differently depending on whether its slider is opened or closed. Probably just give it a try with both opened/closed slider.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a method different to the suggested by Arhimed and it seems to work well (I use it to draw a custom Field differently - when the device is tilted). I have a method

```
protected void myOrientation() {
    // portrait is true when dh > dw
    boolean portrait = (Display.getOrientation() == Display.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    // dw and dh = real horizontal and vertical dimensions of display - regardless of device orientation
    int dw = portrait ? Math.min(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight()) : Math.max(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
    int dh = portrait ? Math.max(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight()) : Math.min(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

    // here I draw my custom Field

    invalidate();
}
```

and call it once in the constructor and after that it is called on every Accelerometer event:

```
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements AccelerometerListener {

private MyScreen() {
    if (AccelerometerSensor.isSupported()) {
        orientationChannel = AccelerometerSensor.openOrientationDataChannel( Application.getApplication() );
        orientationChannel.addAccelerometerListener(this);
    }
    ....
} 


public void onData(AccelerometerData accData) {
    if (old != accData.getOrientation()) {
        myField.myOrientation();
    }
}
```

Maybe this helps you and yes - you have to check, if the keyboard is slided out on Torch

Regards
Alex